# Обработка событий

Tags: javascript, html

Все чаще вижу, что обработчики событий вешают не на сам элемент, который вызвал событие, и даже не на родителя, а на объект window. Получается так, что все обработчики находятся на window и работают через механизм делегации. Естественно, за исключением тех, которые не умеют всплывать.

Хотелось бы узнать как производительнее и легче браузеру? Или хотя бы как можно это *правильно* протестировать?

Давайте считать, что у нас на странице много (100-500) обработчиков и сама страница это лес из div'ов. Мне кажется, за счет того, что между самим событием и его всплытием до window происходит некоторое время + время расходуется на выбор правильного делегата. Это может влиять на производительность. Помогите разобраться или это я бешусь с жиру и всё равно как делать на самом деле.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Браузеру производительней обрабатывать события на месте. Имхо не так много причин за вешать обработчик на window, зато куча против.

- Событию нужно всплыть до window, его могут перехватить и отменить
- Обработчики будут возбуждаться на все события данного типа и проверять не возникло ли оно на нужном элементе и нужно ли его обработать
- Обработка будет откладываться пока событие всплывает и обрабатывается более конкретными обработчиками
- Нельзя будет выстроить порядок обработки повесив дополнительные обработчики на родительский элемент чтобы они выполнились после

Answer (score 1):

Первое к чему должен стремится каждый человек, это позаботится чтобы его дело приносило только удовольствие.
 Если Вы будите писать обработчики на `window`, то Вам придется вести собственный реестр чтобы событие дошло таки до получателя и скорее всего элементам придется давать уникальные `id`. И мне кажется что если Вы не пишите какой-то фраймворк, то данная затея будет неоправданна. Ведь согласитесь, в реальности не бывает таких вложенностей чтобы заметить разницу производительности на пару кликах. 
 И если тест проведенной под запредельно высокой нагрузкой, которую в жизни не может существовать, покажет существенную разницу, то это может натолкнуть на негативные мысли склоняющие к оптимизации событий. А в реальности события не являются предметом оптимизации, если это не `mousemove`, `scroll` или что-то связанное с `requestAnimationFrame`. Да и то оптимизация сводится к созданию единой точки распространения (создание сервиса, менеджера) и создана лишь для того чтобы минимизировать обращение к `dom` элементам, работа с которыми является наиболее узким местом при оптимизации приложения.